# Sagging gate: tools to adjust anchor

Tags: wood, woodworking, gates

I'm trying to fix our wooden gate, which isn't closing well as it is sagging. I'd like to fix it by pushing the anchor inwards, but I don't know which tools to help me do that. I tried hammering it, but it is too hard and it doesn't move at all.

The upper anchor (first image) does not have an actual bolt to help me adjust it, whereas the lower one (second image) has it.

Two questions:

1. What tools would you recommend to do the job of pushing the upper anchor inwards?
2. Is it worth considering replacing the upper anchor with an anchor like the lower one (with a bolt) to help any future adjustments?

[image: upper anchor]

[image: lower anchor]

Answer (score 3):

The simplest solution I can think of depends upon whether the upper hinge point is threaded or not. If it is threaded, then get a cheater bar, a piece of pipe big enough to fit around the end of the hinge, and give the hinge a twist until the gate no longer sags. If it is a pounded in hinge, get a big hammer.

If that doesn't work, replace the upper hinge with an adjustable one or adjust the lower hinge so that it pokes out more.

Comment: I got a steel pipe and was able to adjust the anchor as it seems to be threaded. That worked perfectly and fixed my issue. Thanks so much for the prompt help!

Comment: That type of large threaded screw is called a *lag bolt* or *lag anchor*.